# C++ inherited function in cpp file

Tags: c++

`Topic` is a base class with a method called `possibleEvaluationQuestions()` declared in `Topic`. `AlgebraTopic` is a subclass of `Topic`. In `AlgebraTopic`’s cpp file I’ve declared the function:

```
vector<EvaluationQuestion *> AlgebraTopic::possibleEvaluationQuestions()
{
    return vector<EvaluationQuestion *>();
}
```

But get the warning "out-of-line definition..” in Xcode. It says ‘possibleEvaluationQuestions()’ isn’t declared in `AlgebraTopic`, which it isn’t, but, it is declared in the superclass `Topic`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to redeclare it in `AlgebraTopic` header

Comment: Really? Despite it being declared in `Topic`?

Comment: Yes, you want a new definition for `AlgebraTopic`, so you must redeclare it

Answer (score 0):

When you define :

```
vector<EvaluationQuestion *> AlgebraTopic::possibleEvaluationQuestions()
```

The compiler is looking for the corresponding declaration : in C++ you can't define a member function without having it declared.

The declaration of the base class function is the declaration of *another, different* function : both exist for any `AlgebraTopic` object.

You can convince yourself with this :

```
struct X
{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base\n"; }   
};

struct Y : X
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "derived\n"; }
};

int main(){

    Y y;
    y.foo();
    y.X::foo();
}
```

Output:

> derived
>
> base